# Please check my solution of a problem in combinatorics regarding partitions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A lift automatically operated has a further computer facility of recording how many people leave the lift at each floor. It starts at floor $1$ and goes up to floor $6$. If $8$ people consisting of $3$ men and $5$ women use the lift and the computer can distinguish between man and woman, then how many different records are possible of people leaving the lift.

My solution: This problem is equivalent, to distributing $3$ objects into $6$ baskets and simultaneously distributing $5$ objects in to those 6 baskets.
Since the two events are independent,so the number of distributions is equal to, $$N={3+6-1\choose{6-1}}{.}{5+6-1\choose{6-1}}$$
$$={8\choose{5}}.{10\choose{5}}=14112$$

Therefore,the number of different possible records are $14,112$.

$\text{Note : }$Now,is this solution correct? If not, then please tell me where my thought process is going wrong. Thank you! :)

Comment: Looks okay to me.  The only question is: if the lift *starts* at floor 1, how many of the people using the lift will get off at floor 1?

Comment: Anything can happen in mathematics! :P

Comment: Depending on the definition of "record" it could also distinguish between other things. Here are some examples: between the order people left at each floor, whether people can forget to leave, so the elevator has to go down again, whether everyone could fit into the elevator at once, whether the women can give birth while in the lift.

If you are sure of what the word "record" means, then just disregard this.

Comment: I hope the woman is not pregnant! :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by OP is correct if we allow the possibility that some (or all) of the people will exit on the first floor.

As suggested in the Comment by @GrahamKemp, a reasonable interpretation of the problem is that "starts at floor 1 and goes up to floor 6" meant everyone exits on floors 2 through 6, in which case the number of possibilities is smaller:

$$ N={3+5-1\choose{5-1}}{.}{5+5-1\choose{5-1}}=4410 $$

There is also the further (theoretical) possibility that some passengers [will never exit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.T.A._(song))!

Comment: What is that hyperlink for ? Am I missing some obvious joke?

Comment: @QuiGonnJinn: Yes, the song MTA tells about Charlie who could never leave the Boston subway because of an exit fare imposed after he boarded one morning on his way to work.  The chorus includes the lines: "He will ride forever 'neath the streets of Boston. He's the man who never returned."  Drawing comparison to elevator riders who might (improbably) never get off...